Why is the cart increment not working properly?
I need to increase or decrease the quantity of items on the cart, but when I click the increment button for a particular item, it increases the quantity of all the items in the cart.
Here's my code - what am I doing wrong?
const [items, setItems] = useState(existingCartArray);
const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);

const handleAdjustQuantity = (itemId, newQuantity) => {
    // Update the quantity of the item with the given itemId
    const updatedItems = items.map((item) =>
      item.id === itemId ? { ...item, quantity: newQuantity } : item
    );
    setItems(updatedItems);
    setQuantity(newQuantity);
  };

 return (
    <Modal show={show} onHide={onHide}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Receipt</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        {(existingCartArray).map((item) => (
          <div  key={item.id}>
          
              <div key={item.id} style={{display:'flex', justifyItems:'left', padding:'0em 0em 0em 1em'}}>
              <Button variant="danger" style={{fontSize:'.6em', height:'30px'}} onClick={() => handleRemoveItem(item.id)}>Remove</Button>
              <div style={{display:'flex', padding:"0em 0em 0em 10em"}}>
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => handleAdjustQuantity(item.id, quantity + 1)}>+</Button>
              <span> {quantity}</span>
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => handleAdjustQuantity(item.id, quantity - 1)}>-</Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );



When I click the increment button for a particular item, it increases
the quantity of all the items in the cart.

This is because you have implemented a single quantity state that is used to increment from and is rendered for each item element in the items array.
You appear to be updating a quantity property on each item in the array though, so update the logic to increment the specific item's quantity property and render this property. Remove the quantity state since you no longer need it.
const [items, setItems] = useState(existingCartArray);

const handleAdjustQuantity = (itemId, amount) => {
  setItems(items => items.map((item) =>
    item.id === itemId
      ? {
        ...item,
        quantity: item.quantity + amount
      } : item
  ));
};

return (
  <Modal show={show} onHide={onHide}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title>Receipt</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>      
          <div
            style={{
              display: 'flex',
              justifyItems: 'left',
              padding: '0em 0em 0em 1em'
            }}
          >
            <Button
              variant="danger"
              style={{ fontSize: '.6em', height: '30px' }}
              onClick={() => handleRemoveItem(item.id)}
            >
              Remove
            </Button>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', padding: "0em 0em 0em 10em" }}>
              <Button
                variant="primary"
                onClick={() => handleAdjustQuantity(item.id, 1)}
              >
                +
              </Button>
              <span>{item.quantity}</span>
              <Button
                variant="primary"
                onClick={() => handleAdjustQuantity(item.id, -1)}
              >
                -
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </Modal.Body>
  </Modal>
);

